# Importing many to many relationship (Django)

Tags: django, python-2.7

I want to import data to many to many fields.

My code below imports the data, but only applies one relationship to the model (not two, as I've asked it to do below by importing it twice- where I wrote "cat = ...")

In my example below, I want it to import cat (category) from columns 4 & 11. My code below only applies one category to the model (not both).

How can I get it to apply both fields to the model? Im using python 2.7

```
import csv

l = list(csv.reader(open('test_data.csv', 'rb')))

Gender_CHOICES = {
    'Male': 1,
    'Female': 2,
    'Unisex': 3,
}

Stock_CHOICES = {
    'in stock': 1,
    'low stock': 2,
    'out of stock': 3,
    'discountinued': 4
}

for i in l[1:]:
        cat = m.Category.objects.get_or_create(category_name = i[4],[11])[0]
        prod = m.Product(
            name = i[0],
            link = i[1],
            description = i[6],
            brand = i[7],
            colour = i[10],
            gender = Gender_CHOICES[i[8]] if i[8] in Gender_CHOICES else 3,
            store = m.Store.objects.get_or_create(store_name = i[2])[0]
            )
        prod.save()
        var = m.Variation(
            product = prod,
            variation = "default"
            )
        var.save()
        img = m.Image(
            variation = var,
            image = i[5]
            )
        img.save()
        size = m.Size(
            variation = var
            )
        size.save()
        price = m.Price(
            variation = var,
            price = float(i[3])
            )
        price.save()
        stock = m.Stock(
            size = size,
            stock = Stock_CHOICES[i[9]] if i[9] in Stock_CHOICES else 4
            )
        stock.save()
        prod.category.add(cat)
```

Sample of CSV:

```
prod_name,prod_link,store_name,prod_price,category,image_default,prod_description,prod_brand,gender,prod_stock,category1
Bliss Firm Baby Firm Lifting & Volumising Serum 30ml - Serum,http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=dnw*50nuNL8&offerid=287549.2554637&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.asos.com%2Fau%2FBliss%2FBliss-Firm-Baby-Firm-Lifting-Volumising-Serum-30ml%2FProd%2Fpgeproduct.aspx%3Fiid%3D3936070%26istCompanyId%3Df448b47d-6b90-4b9b-a52d-eb6058c99b1c%26istItemId%3Dwxqqpxxmi%26istBid%3Dt,Asos,117,Skin Care Body Creams & Moisturisers,http://images.asos-media.com/inv/media/0/7/0/6/3936070/serum/image1xxl.jpg,Firm Baby Firm Lifting & Volumising Serum by Bliss Designed to boost collagen and elasticity Concentrated formula with a water-free aloe base Aims to plump skin from the inside out,Bliss,Female,
Yes To Carrots Day Cream 50ml - Carrots,http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=dnw*50nuNL8&offerid=287549.2825448&type=15&murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.asos.com%2Fau%2FYES-TO%2FYes-To-Carrots-Day-Cream-50ml%2FProd%2Fpgeproduct.aspx%3Fiid%3D4254119%26istCompanyId%3Df448b47d-6b90-4b9b-a52d-eb6058c99b1c%26istItemId%3Dwiqwwawpm%26istBid%3Dt,Asos,21,Skin Care Body Creams & Moisturisers,http://images.asos-media.com/inv/media/9/1/1/4/4254119/carrots/image1xxl.jpg,Day cream by Yes To Carrots 95% natural ingredients Including carrots and sweet almond oil Rich moisturising formula Naturally nourishes to promote softer skin Suitable for normal to dry skin types Product size: 50ml,YES TO,Female,Belts
```

[image]

Comment: The code you have posted is incomplete... can you show us how you are saving both the Product and Category models?

Comment: Also, show a part of the CSV file.

Comment: I have posted the complete code, and part of my CSV file too

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the problem is with Object creation. I think the following is what you are looking for :

```
....
....
for i in l[1:]:
        cat_1 = m.Category.objects.get_or_create(category_name = i[4])
        cat_2 = m.Category.objects.get_or_create(category_name = i[11])
....
....
prod.category.add(cat_1)
prod.category.add(cat_2)
```

Comment: I would also like to do this in a queryset (so I can use the drop-down menu in admin to apply pre-set values to a mode). I tried this, but it only works for a foreign key: `def Category(self, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(tag=Tag.objects.get(name__iexact='Shoes'), updated=timezone.now())`